# Firebase auth:import doesn't import password SHA256

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication, firebase-tools

i'm trying to migrate users to firebase using the cli command auth:import.

My passwordHash is a SHA256 without salt from PHP hash function hash('sha256', $password);

When i use auth:import my user is added to my firebase users but without the password.

```
firebase auth:import user.json --hash-algo=SHA256 --rounds=64
```

For the passwordHash string i've tried with/without base64 and with diffrents --rounds (0/1/64/80 ...)

There's my user.json

passwordHash is **mypass**
SHA256 **ea71c25a7a602246b4c39824b855678894a96f43bb9b71319c39700a1e045222**
Base64 **ZWE3MWMyNWE3YTYwMjI0NmI0YzM5ODI0Yjg1NTY3ODg5NGE5NmY0M2JiOWI3MTMxOWMzOTcwMGExZTA0NTIyMg==**

```
{
  "users": [
    {
      "localId": 1,
      "email" : "test@demo.com",
      "emailVerified": true,
      "passwordHash" : "ZWE3MWMyNWE3YTYwMjI0NmI0YzM5ODI0Yjg1NTY3ODg5NGE5NmY0M2JiOWI3MTMxOWMzOTcwMGExZTA0NTIyMg==",
      "displayName" : "test",
      "createdAt" : 1501452000000,
    }
  ]
}
```

I've tried with a MD5 and it was working so i wondering what i've missing here.

Thank's, Julien.

Comment: Maybe this can help https://github.com/firebase/firebase-tools/issues/337

Comment: @DoesData Thank's for the comment. I've already read this one, i did not get same error message but i've tried differents rounds and base64 string because of this thread.

Comment: @Julien, I think https://github.com/firebase/firebase-tools/issues/337 can help.

`ea71c25a7a602246b4c39824b855678894a96f43bb9b71319c39700a1e045222 ` is actually base16 encoded. The base64 string should be `6nHCWnpgIka0w5gkuFVniJSpb0O7m3ExnDlwCh4EUiI=`. I verified it worked.

Comment: @wyhao31 Thank's, the problem was my sha256 was base16 encoded. There is a way to know that ? Anyway thank's and if you post your comment as a answer i'll mark it as the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`ea71c25a7a602246b4c39824b855678894a96f43bb9b71319c39700a1e04‌​5222` is actually hex, or base16 encoded. So the base64 string should be `6nHCWnpgIka0w5gkuFVniJSpb0O7m3ExnDlwCh4EUiI=`.

---

How can I know the hashed string is base16 encoded? I think the lib you use should indicate that. For instance, if I use NodeJS, the following code can be used to generate the string you got (`ea71c25a7a6...`):

```
const crypto = require('crypto');
let hash = crypto.createHash('sha256');
hash.update('mypass').digest('hex');
```

I call `.digest('hex')` to convert bytes to hex, so I know the string is hex. If you specify `base64` instead of `hex` inside `digest` function, you can get correct base64 encoded string.